# SQL как хранить повторяющиеся записи

Tags: mysql, sql

у меня есть таблица с вот такими строками:

```
id: 1 value: 0.50
id: 2 value: 0.51
id: 3 value: 0.50
```

То есть у некоторых строк значение `value` может повторяться(это нормально для моего проекта, я так и хочу). Но когда пытаюсь записать повторяющееся значение, SQL ругается:`Duplicate entry '0.05' for key 'value'`

Как я могу избежать этого?

P.S хранить строки в разных таблицах не могу(и не хочу)

Comment: У вы удалите индекс уникальности на поле value, тогда ошибки не будет.

Comment: @AlexanderSemikashev да, точно спасибо, заметил, просто обычно создавал базы кодом, а тут решил вручную(